# unable to create aws spot instance using terraform - Error: "MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded"

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, spot-instances

Friends, I'm facing below error when I'm trying to create a spot instance using terraform.

> "Error: Error requesting spot instances: MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded:
> Max spot instance count exceeded
> status code: 400, request id: 19c590fd-c352-4bbd-8915-678ac3e32474"

I have already checked my limit in aws console and its showing 32vcpu(image3) and also currently I don't have any running spot instance template or running instances (image2). My issue here is, I can able to create spot instance directly through aws console but not possible through terraform v0.14.5 (image1). I have attached all the screenshot with this post for better insight. I really dont know how to fix this, even aws support team just asking me to check my limit which I already done. So, any helps on this is case from this community is highly appreciable.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please post code as text blocks, not only screenshots?

Comment: @Marcin - How that is going to benefit for this case now? Anyway, I'll share with you personally, if you want my code.

Answer (score 1):

Friends - Finally, I found a way to resolve this issue. The main cause for this error is "block_duration_minutes = 120" which I mentioned in the "createinstance.tf" file. Since, I'm specifying AZ for my instance, its not possible for me to mention "block_duration_minute". hence, I should remove this parameter to make it work. Read more about this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_instance_request

Thanks for the support.